# E-mail in the source : a no-go?

Tags: html, email, web-crawler, spam-prevention

I have a contact form where the email is actually accessible in the source, because I'm using a cgi file to process it. My concern are the mail crawlers, and I was wondering if this is a no-go and I should switch to another more secure form. Or, if there was some tricks to 'confuse' the crawlers ? Thanks for your ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always convert the characters of email addresses (including the mailto statement if applicable) into character entities. This seems to work nicely, I have yet to receive automated spam on certain email addresses which are available in this manner on different websites. [This converter](http://www.wbwip.com/wbw/emailencoder.html) illustrates what I mean.

Answer (score 7):

If you're putting the *destination* address of the email in the HTML form, then not only is it a problem for mail crawlers, but **spammers will use your contact form for spamming other people**. All they would have to do is submit the same form with a different address in that field, and your mail server will happily send their message to a third party. You do not want to do this, as your server will quickly become blacklisted for sending spam.

Answer (score 3):

If by source you mean the HTML source, then absolutely that's a problem.  Can you edit the cgi file to hardcode it there?

Comment: Thanks guys, all your answers were very helpful. I finally edited the script, it's called formmail.pl, and it's written in perl. Still testing but looks good.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should avoid that to minimize spamming.

An easy way would be to just obfuscate the e-mail, replacing `.` with `-dot-` and `@` with `-at-` etc.

- If a human needs the address, he knows what that he has to perform
- If your CGI script takes this address as input, it has to de-obfuscate first, reverting all obfuscations.